# Team foundation server: Hiding/disabling issue tracking?

Tags: team-foundation-server

We're considering using Team Foundation Server for our teams. Because we'll be setting up an issue tracking software sometime later this year, we don't want our teams to start using the TFS issue tracking (i.e. submitting bug reports, user stories, and so forth). Is there any way to disable or remove the TFS issue tracking (preferably globally, not per project)?

Comment: By 'Issue Tracking', do you mean following work items? Or do you mean, lock down the ability to create work items, including but not limited to bugs, user stories, epics, features etc...?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I disabling issue tracking I mean locking down the ability to submit bug reports, user stories, and so forth. I'll edit my post to clearify this.

Comment: Given TFS is an ALM, and one of its main sale points is issue tracking, it's pretty well baked in. You could permission it though, to prevent access to the project pages on the web view and via VS. Are you just going to use it for Source Control? TFS is very good at the ALM side, why not consider using it for issue tracking?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. We have a team working towards deploying a issue tracking solution, but as far as I know they've got other products on their short list.